# Why equals return false in this situation?

Tags: java, list, equals

Here is the default JDK 8 implementation of AbstractList.equals()

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof List))
        return false;
    ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
    ListIterator e2 = ((List) o).listIterator();
    while(e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
        E o1 = e1.next();
        Object o2 = e2.next();
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    }
    return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());
}
```

I have following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List list = new LinkedList<List>();
        List innerList = new LinkedList<List>();
        list.add(innerList);

        System.out.println(list.equals(innerList));
    }
```

In my opinion the two lists here are not equals and it should return false. And the compiler return false. My question is why? In the last line 
return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());

e1.hasNext() is false and e2.hasNext() is false so overall it should return true. Why it return false ?

Comment: list contains a single element (innerList). inner list is empty. how could they possibly be equal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code compares an empty List to a List with a single element, so of course `equals` would return false.

`return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());` evaluates to `return !(true || false);` (since one List is empty and the other is not) which evaluates to `return !true`, which is false.

Answer (score 1):

actually this sentence

> e1.hasNext() is false and e2.hasNext() is false ...

is incorrect. Here's why: e1 is the iterator over `list` and e2 is the iterator over `innerList`.

`list` contains one element (due to `list.add(innerList)`) so its iterator has one element to iterate over so `e1.hasNext()` is `true`. Hence `e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext()` yields `true`, so `!(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext())` evaluates to `false`.